# Ruby: showing one subarray per page

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am using Ruby (+ Sinatra) to work on one of my web projects.

I have an array with quite a bit of content and only want to display 10 of the array elements per page.

---

So what I did so far is:

- creating an array with all of the content

  ```
  ary = ["ex1", "ex2", "ex3", … ,"ex60" ] // all elements
  ```
- splitting the array into subarrays

  ```
  ary.each_slice(10).to_a // subarrays with fewer content
  ```

Now, I need a way to split the subarrays into single arrays and give them a name,

for example:

```
@subAry1 # ex1, ex2, ex3, … ex10
@subAry2 # ex11, ex12, ex13, … ex20
@subAry3 # ex21, ex22, ex23, … ex30
```

I stuck on creating these arrays with a continuing number in the array name.

---

When I would have my arrays split, I would use this in my .erb file:

```
<% currentAry = @subAry1 %>
<% currentAry.each do |element| %><%= element %><% end %>
```

and this to change the content, if the "next" button gets pressed:

```
currentAry = @subAry + '1'
```

---

Can somebody help me, or is it even an effective way, to split/display array elments on my page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about an array of arrays? Here's something to help you get started.

```
all = ary.each_slice(10).to_a
current_page = 0
```

In the ERB file:

```
<% all[current_page].each do |element| %><%= element %><% end %>
```

and after the "next" button gets pressed

```
current_page += 1
```